# Basic Objective-C memory management syntax

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, variable-assignment

I have a property defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *someObject;
```

I'm currently using this assignment statement:

```
someObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

In terms of **memory managment** is the above assignment statement equivalent to:

```
self.someObject = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Assume `@synthesize someObject;` is in the `@implementation` section. Also I'm not using ARC.

Comment: First off, you need to define whether or not you're using ARC.  And if you're a beginner and not using ARC then you should probably explain why, since most new code from now on out will be written using ARC, and non-ARC syntax will only be used for maintenance.

Comment: @HotLicks No I'm not using ARC. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  The following is based on the EDITED version of the original post, where "assign" has been replaced with "retain" ---

Yes, the two are "equivalent", in that they will both result in leaving the MyClass object (properly) retained with a retain count of 1 in the property.  The second version goes through some extra work, which may or may not be an issue, depending on how performance-sensitive you are.

Some people argue you should never use the property reference (ie, `self.propname`) from within the class, but instead reference the instance variable, especially for initialization and deallocation.  Others argue just the opposite.  I generally favor always using the property reference, except during initialization where (as in this case) using it might result in an extraneous retain/autorelease.

Comment: I'm curious about the downsides of directly using the instance variable for initialization. I suppose using the instance variable directly ignores `nonatomic` in the property definition. However it seems like that makes the code "safer" regarding concurrency while potentially paying a performance penalty.

Comment: Well, there are some people who are hot and heavy into "key value observing" and setting the instance variable directly bypasses automatic notifications.  Never mucked with it myself, so I don't know how much of an issue this is.  And some people are just "purists" and have determined that Style A is "right" and Style B is "wrong".  I don't argue with them except when they're insisting that I change my own code.  I tend to *prefer* any "usual practice" (vs enforced standard) that makes code easier to understand and harder to write incorrectly.